# How to make gvim start with the latest closed files?

Tags: vim

I googled a solution as (c.f. http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Open_the_last_edited_file):

```
" Go to last file(s) if invoked without arguments.
autocmd VimLeave * nested if (!isdirectory($HOME . "/.vim")) |
    \ call mkdir($HOME . "/.vim") |
    \ endif |
    \ execute "mksession! " . $HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim"

autocmd VimEnter * nested if argc() == 0 && filereadable($HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim") |
    \ execute "source " . $HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim"
```

But it seems has some conflict (in vim7.4):

> ```
> processing vim/vimfiles/ftpugins/latex-suite/folding.vim with error
> E227: mapping Tex_RefreshFolds has exists
> ```

What's the problem and how to fix this then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, a Vim session also stores all currently defined mappings. In your case, that mapping interferes with a `<unique>`-constrained mapping from the Latex suite.

Usually, you don't need to persist your mappings; they come from plugins and are automatically re-defined on the next Vim startup (only manually entered `:map`s would be lost). Remove this behavior via

```
:set sessionoptions-=options
```

in your `~/.vimrc` (it'll also reduce the size of your session file and make it load faster).

Comment: I didn't understand it well, did I add you line without any change in my _vimrc? It seems not help.

Comment: It might be something else (see my other answer for a more coarse method), but check that the value isn't overridden somewhere later via `:set sessionoptions?`.

Answer (score 1):

The error doesn't do harm if it's complaining about the same existing mapping (presumably restored from the session). If you can't fix the root cause, you can (as a last resort) just silence the error (and any others) by adding `:silent!` to the original autocmd:

```
...
\ execute "silent! source " . $HOME . "/.vim/Session.vim"
```